# Using urllib2.urlopen i get different errors from local vs AWS EB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, urllib2

I have this snippet in a python 2.7.6 app:

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=20)
except:
    warning(sys.exc_info())
```

When I run it locally on my machine i get the error:

```
(<class 'urllib2.URLError'>, URLError(gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known'),), <traceback object at 0x10ca40b00>)
```

When I run it on AWS EB I get

```
(<class 'urllib2.URLError'>, URLError(gaierror(-5, 'No address associated with hostname'),), <traceback object at 0x7f59958a1050>)
```

Why do I get different error messages? I believe I running the same versions of everything in both environments.

Comment: Its probably due to a different version of python. What solution stack are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'req' variable isn't a variable with a properly formatted URL or there might be a spelling error.

Regardless I would suggest using requests library for this.

```
import requests
try:
    response = requests.get('http://www.whatever.co/',timeout=20)
except URLError as e:
    print(e)
print(response)
# you should get a 200 response
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yep.  But do you know why I get different error messages from AWS and local?